# Why isn't syntax highlighting for C++ working?

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

Does Programmers Stack Exchange site support syntax-highlighting for C++?

The reason I ask is that the code in [my question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/125569/programmically-generating-htmlcss) isn't highlighted in Firefox 8.

Answer (score 7):

Yes it does.

However, unless you [explicitly tell the highlighter which language it is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints) by including:

```
<!-- language: lang-cpp -->
```

at the start of your code snippet, it uses the tags to decide which language the code is in.

As you've tagged the question [html](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html) and [css](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/css) it's going to assume that the code is either HTML or CSS, not C++.

So either retag the question or use the language hint.

Comment: I retagged it, since it was unrelated to "design" and "functional programming" anyway.